# Specific module has form import errors Django

Tags: python, forms, module

I am having an issues importing forms fields in a specific module
in my forms.py I have the following code

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from koalified.seeker.models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    ver_password = forms.CharField(label=(u' Verify Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
            model = Seeker
            exclude = ('user','verified','premium')

    def clean_username(self):
            ''' Checking username availability '''
            username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            try:
                    User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                    if len(username)  >= 5 and len(username) < 21:
                        return self.cleaned_data['username']
                    else:
                        raise forms.ValidationError("Username must be between 5 and 20 characters")
            raise forms.ValidationError("That username is already in use")

    def clean_ver_password(self):
            password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
            ver_password = self.cleaned_data.get('ver_password')

            if not ver_password:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")
            if password != ver_password:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
            return ver_password
```

I keep getting a view does not exist error, which I have researched and it suggested to go into the shell and try to import. Here is the following output of the import

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/home/jmcguffee1/django.koalified.com/koalified/koalified/seeker/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    class RegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    File "/home/jmcguffee1/django.koalified.com/koalified/koalified/seeker/forms.py", line 7, in RegistrationForm
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'
```

I have looked through some issues and have found that people may have had spelling issues, but I have tried this over and over again and can't get this to load the forms in my other modules work just fine such as my login form

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

I have tried manually importing the fields and it works, i.e.

```
from django.forms.fields import CharField, EmailField
username = CharField()
```

This works fine
I have gone back into my shell and imported django.forms and tried to load it from there

> > > from django import forms
> > >       username = forms.CharField(label=(u'Username'))
> > >       username

I have checked for a cyclic call in my models.py and views.py and there is no other import for django forms. It seems that this specific module is not loading the form field properly. More information can be provided if this is not clear enough.

Here was the solution to the answer

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> print 'form is : ', forms
form is :  <module 'django.forms' from '/home/jmcguffee1/django.koalified.com/kf/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/django/forms/__init__.pyc'>
>>> from koalified.seeker.models import *
>>> print 'form is : ', forms
form is :  <module 'django.forms.forms' from '/home/jmcguffee1/django.koalified.com/kf/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.3-py2.6.egg/django/forms/forms.pyc'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Star imports are a sure way to make a mess of a namespace. Try adding a couple print statements as shown below and check what the "form" name is bound too after the star import

```
from django import forms
print "forms is :", forms
# ....
from koalified.seeker.models import *
print "forms is :", forms
```

Comment: That worked I just changed the import * to import the specific models

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess: in your models.py file, do you import your forms module? I'm guessing you do. Then this line is the problem:

```
from koalified.seeker.models import *
```

That imports *every* global name in the models module into the current namespace. And since one of those names is `forms`, which refers to the current forms module, it therefore overwrites your import at the top: so `forms` now refers to the same module, not to the Django forms module.

This is why **you should never use `from x import *`. Either just do `from koalified.seeker import models` and refer to `models.Seeker` etc, or do `from koalified.seeker.models import Seeker, TheOtherModel` etc. IMO the first is better, but that's a matter of preference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to python and django, so I am still used to Java